# How to intercept C library calls in windows?

Tags: c, windows, dll, trace

I have a `devilish-gui.exe`, a `devilish.dll` and a `devilish.h` from a C codebase that has been lost.
`devilish-gui` is still used from the customer and it uses devilish.dll

`devilish.h` is poorly documented in a 30-pages pdf: it exposes a few C functions that behave in very different ways according to the values in the structs provided as arguments.

Now, I have to use devilish.dll to write a new devilish-webservice. No, I can't rewrite it.

The documentation is almost useless, but since I have devilish-gui.exe I'd like to write a different implementation of the devilish.h so that it log function's call and arguments in a file, and than calls the original dll function. Something similar to what [ltrace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ltrace) does on linux, but specialized for this weird library.

How can I write such "intercepting" dll on windows and inject it between devilish.dll and devilish-gui.exe?

Comment: Could you implement your own `devilish.dll` that internally performs `LoadLibrary()` on the original version, and you implement all the APIs to call the original version except for those calls you actually want to annotate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LD\_PRELOAD equivalent for Windows to preload shared libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178257/ld-preload-equivalent-for-windows-to-preload-shared-libraries)

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd like to do, but on windows I've no idea of how to force devilish-gui load my own implementation. The only constraint is that I can't change neither devilish-gui nor devilish.dll.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of possibilities:

1. Use [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/).
2. If you put your implementation of `devilish.dll` in the same directory as `devilish-gui.exe`, and move the real implementation of `devilish.dll` into a subdirectory, Windows will load your implementation instead of the real one.  Your implementation can then forward to the real one.  I'm assuming that `devilish-gui` isn't [hardened against search path attacks.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2389418?wa=wsignin1.0)
3. Another approach would be to use [IntelliTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264915.aspx) to collect a trace log of all the calls into `devilish.dll`.

Comment: Good links. Can you suggest any open source alternative to Detours? In particular, the devilish.dll and gui are x86 programs but we are running them on x64 windows 8 desktops.

Comment: @GiacomoTesio Some quick googling results in a reference to [EasyHook](http://code.google.com/p/easyhook-continuing-detours/), but I haven't used it, so I can't comment further.  If you have VS 2012, Intellitrace might help, too.

Comment: IntelliTrace is mot an option, since the gui was written in C.