# How to override standard libc functions?

Tags: c, malloc, overriding, libc

For example, if I want to override malloc(), what's the best way to do it?

Currently the simplest way I know of is:

malloc.h

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#define malloc my_malloc
void* my_malloc (size_t size);
```

foobar.c

```
#include "malloc.h"

void foobar(void)
{
    void* leak = malloc(1024);
}
```

The problem with this approach is that we now have to use "malloc.h" and can never use "stdlib.h".  Is there a way around this?  I'm particularly interested in importing 3rd party libraries without modifying them at all, but forcing them into calling my custom libc functions (like malloc).

Comment: Why can't you just use another name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding C library functions, calling original](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19023018/overriding-c-library-functions-calling-original)

Comment: @Rizier123 "I'm particularly interested in importing 3rd party libraries without modifying them at all, but forcing them into calling my custom libc functions (like malloc)."

Answer (score 10):

The short answer is you probably want to use the LD_PRELOAD trick: [What is the LD_PRELOAD trick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick)

That approach basically inserts your own custom shared library on runtime before any other shared library is loaded, exporting the functions you want to override, such as malloc(). By the time the other shared libraries are loaded your symbol is already there and gets preference when resolving calls to that symbol name from other libraries. From within your malloc() wrapper/replacement you can even chose to call the next malloc symbol, which typically would be the actual libc symbol.

This blog post has a lot of comprehensive information about this method:

http://samanbarghi.com/blog/2014/09/05/how-to-wrap-a-system-call-libc-function-in-linux/

Note that example is overriding libc's write() and puts() functions, but the same logic applies for malloc():

> LD_PRELOAD allows a shared library to be loaded before any other libraries. So all I need to do is to write a shared library that overrides write and puts functions. If we wrap these functions, we need a way to call the real functions to perform the system call. dlsym just do that for us [man 3 dlsym]: > The function dlsym() takes a “handle” of a dynamic library returned by dlopen() and the null-terminated symbol name, returning the address where that symbol is loaded into memory. If the symbol is not found, in the specified library or any of the libraries that were automatically loaded by dlopen() when that library was loaded, dlsym() returns NULL…
>
> So inside the wrapper function we can use dlsym to get the address of the related symbol in memory and call the glibc function. Another approach can be calling the syscall directly, both approaches will work.

That blog post also describes a compile-time method I did not know about that involves passing a linker flag to ld, "--wrap":

> Another way of wrapping functions is by using linker at the link time. GNU linker provides an option to wrap a function for a symbol [man 1 ld]: > Use a wrapper function for symbol. Any undefined reference to symbol will be resolved to “__wrap_symbol”. Any undefined reference to “__real_symbol” will be resolved to symbol.

The handy thing about LD_PRELOAD is that might allow you to change the malloc() implementation on production applications for quick testing, or even allow the user to select (I do this in some server applications) which implementation to use. The '[tcmalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html)' library for example can be easily inserted into an application to evaluate performance gains in heavily threaded applications (where tcmalloc tends to perform a lot better than libc's malloc implementation).

Finally if you're on Windows, perhaps try this: [LD_PRELOAD equivalent for Windows to preload shared libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178257/ld-preload-equivalent-for-windows-to-preload-shared-libraries)

Comment: Note that this pretty much only necessary if you want to override the standard library with another shared library.  If you want to override with a symbol *in your application itself*, you can just define the symbol in your application -- the application elf object is (by definition) the first object loaded (before *any* shared objects, including LD_PRELOAD), so (non weak) symbols in it take priority.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Interestingly, just defining the symbol also works in a statically-linked context (where there is no concept of object load ordering as you described). I'm not sure where this behavior is specified, as I would have expected a `multiple definition` error from the linker.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: static linking uses the order specified on the linker command line -- each library is linked in order, pulling in any symbols that are used and undefined in previous objects and defined in the library.